# How to compare different trends or behaviours among several data series?

Tags: trend, model-comparison

This is my first post on CrossValidated, so please forgive me if I do not supply enough information or if I am wrong in something (I'll try not to! :P ).

I am working with protein data from 100 patients (Healthy vs Pathological), measuring the quantity of each protein. We measure this quantity by the signal these protein give when joined to a marked antibody. Antibodies are not perfect; some join more tightly than others, and some are more specific than others. Therefore, different antibodies designed for the same protein can give different signals, in some cases higher/lower, in other cases, non-especific of the protein. This is a very simplified biological explanation.

The thing is, for each patient we have separated their full proteic sample in 24 parts, by molecular weight (size). So we have 24 signals per protein-antibody combination. For example, in part 1, we would expect finding signal in proteins from 24 KDa to 20 KDa (KDa is a measure of their weigth/size). This is however not exactly true, and we can (and we do) have signal at different ranges of weight. This is important for us; as there can be several causes.

I also have different measures for the same proteins; as for each protein different antibodies have been used (so we have different protein-antibody complexes). I have "empty" measures (just the protein sample without antibodies), and I do not have replicates (I wish... but sadly in research sometimes people do not value replicates enough).

It would look as this:

```
                      Part1 Part2 Part3 Part4 Part5  ...
Protein1_AntibodyX      12    22   83    22    23    ...
Protein1_AntibodyY      12    12   43    32    13    ...
Protein2_AntibodyZ      45    12   53    62    13    ...
Empty                   3      4    5    12     3    ...
```

Lets suppose that the values are already normalized (I am working on it). Among others, what I have been asked is:

1. Compare the behaviour/trend/signals of different antibodies for the same protein.
2. Compare the behaviour/trend/signals of the signal of the protein-antibodies
   between different patients. Find differences with statistical value (yes, sometimes things are asked very... ambiguously).
3. Stablish a cut-off to select the significant signals for each
   protein-antibody complex.

For points 1 and 2 the process should be similar; comparing trends or behaviours. I am wondering how should I do it (maybe working with models, but which models? And how to stablish that comparison?). This is my main concern; as I am not used to work with these issues, and I would really appreciate some help here.

For point 3, I guess that for this, I will have to do an exploratory analysis of the data. Maybe it would be enough with considering signals higher than the "empty" signals, or with a standard deviation from the mean higher than 2. I would like to know your opinion on this, if possible, because maybe there is a consensus about what to do here that I am not aware of.